# SQL to get records with the same column A, but different B

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-performance

Suppose we have the following table called `meals`:

```
| meal  | stars |
-----------------
| steak |   1   |
| steak |   2   |
| fish  |   4   |
| fish  |   4   |
| salad |   5   |
```

**How can I get records with the same meal, but different stars? I need the records whose only have different stars.**

Result for the table above should be as follows:

```
| meal  | stars |
-----------------
| steak |   1   |
| steak |   2   |
```

I've tried the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM meals t1
INNER JOIN meals t2 ON t1.meal = t2.meal
AND t1.stars <> t2.stars;
```

But it consumes too much time and some noticeable amount of memory.

The actual size of my table is:

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('table_name')); 
 pg_size_pretty 
----------------
 2295 MB
```

So I need to come up with something else and I am asking for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    meals a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  meal
            FROM    meals
            GROUP   BY meal
            HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT stars) > 1
        ) b ON a.meal = b.meal
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/0f32c/1)

OUTPUT

```
╔═══════╦═══════╗
║ MEAL  ║ STARS ║
╠═══════╬═══════╣
║ steak ║     1 ║
║ steak ║     2 ║
╚═══════╩═══════╝
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT meal,stars FROM meals
 GROUP BY meal,stars
 HAVING count(*)=1 and meal in (
    SELECT meal FROM meals
    GROUP BY meal
    HAVING count(*)>1 )
```

Comment: Both your and @j-w solutions are very nice, but the second is slightly faster, so I picked up it.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the fastest way:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    meals m
WHERE   EXISTS (SELECT FROM meals WHERE meal = m.meal AND stars <> m.stars);
```

*"Get all rows, where at least one other meal exists, with the same name but different stars."*

Assuming `NULL` values do not occur.

[SQL Fiddle.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a6563/1)

Answer (score 0):

A simple and faster way to achieve the same results

```
SELECT  
  m.*
FROM    
  meals m
  JOIN meals m2 ON ( m2.meal = m.meal AND m2.stars<>m.stars)
```